# file uploader in php

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

```
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $name=$_FILES['file']['name'];
        $temp=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        move_uploaded_file($temp,$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ."upload/files/".$name);
        $url="http://localhost/upload/files/".$name;



        $sql = "INSERT INTO photo (NAME,link)
       VALUES ('$name','$url')";
```

in this code , sql works, filename successfully updated in database, but i cant move file in directory.

it's errors :

> Warning:
>   move_uploaded_file(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocsupload/files/Screen
>   Shot 2018-05-07 at 11.17.21 AM (2).png): failed to open enter code
>   herestream: No such file or directory in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/upload/upload2.php on line 45
>
> "Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move..."

help please!

Comment: Try checking **$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ."upload/files/".$name** having same value with **"http://localhost/upload/files/".$name**, It should be same

Comment: how I can try this?

Comment: Just try echo them

Comment: thanks , it's work. thank you

Comment: Is file uploading correctly?

Comment: yes, I had the wrong URL. there was no "/" character after $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong url change you url or try this:

```
    <?php
    $target_dir = "uploads/files/";

    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);

    $uploadOk = 1;

    $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

    // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image

    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to upload the file

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
?>
```

For further information you can vist to  https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp